# MFC App crashing when reading from a text file to input to a List Box

Tags: c++, mfc, listbox, fstream

Okay so I am writing a fairly simple dialog based MFC Windows Application and have run into an issue. My dialog contains a few buttons and a list box. When the user clicks one of the buttons, Generate, a text file is opened and its contents are displayed in the list box (m_ctlListBox) line by line. As is, the program builds fine but when the Generate button is pressed the list box seems to disappear and then the app crashes. Any help would be really appreciated!

```
void CMFCApp_noDLLDlg::OnBnClickedGeneratelist()
{
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("C:/Users/.../SampleText.txt", std::ios::in);
    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
    inFile >> std::ws;
    getline(inFile, line);
    CString cs(line.c_str());
    m_ctlListBox.AddString(cs);
    }
    inFile.close();

}
```

Comment: You should / you need to change `while (!inFile.eof())` to `while (!inFile.fail())`, which usually is written as just `while (inFile)`.

Comment: Where does it crash ? What is `getline` ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz: I suppose it is std::getline!

Comment: Maybe you should check if `inFile.open` succeeds.